# A classic semantice makes it possible to characterize the notion of truth/falsity for sentences of a first order language $ \mathcal L_1 ^ {=} $.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

A classic semantic makes it possible to characterize the notion of truth/falsity for sentences of a first order language $ \mathcal L_1 ^ {=} $. Explain importance of ensuring that $ \mathcal L_1 ^ {=} $ - closed formula $ \alpha $ is true in a structure. The formula $ \alpha $ has the following the syntactic form: $ (\exists x\lnot Rx \mathbf a \to \forall xK \mathbf ax) $, where R, K, and $ \mathbf a $ are respectively symbols of predicates (binary) and individual constant.

===================================================================

I'm not sure how to proceed. What exactly does the exercise want?

A formula to be closed means that the formula does not have free variables. And why would a closed formula be more important than an open formula in a structure?

Comment: What is a "classic sequnce" ?

Comment: What textbook are you using ?

Comment: Not clear the link between the part "Explain importance of ensuring ..." and the formula: is it an example of what ?

Comment: "Closed" formulas are *sentence*: when interpreted in a structure $\mathfrak M$ they express "facts" about the objects of the domain of the structure (e.g. natural numbers) and their properties. Example of sentences in the language of arithmetic: $\lnot (0=s(0)), \forall x (x=0)$.

Comment: Thus, our "expectation" is that sentence of the interpreted formal language works like sentences of natural language: they have meaning and a definite truth value. In $\mathbb N$ either ∀x(x=0)  is true (if every number is equal to *zero*) or not.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA My mistake, is semantic not sequence. I'm using Mortari, 2001.

Comment: Sorry... I cannot read Portuguese :-) Having said that, about the "importance of truth value for closed sentences in a structure" my comment above still holds. About the formula, the issue is: what is the structure to be used to interpret it ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The structure is not mentioned. This exercise is very confusing (at least in my opinion). Is it possible to determine if the formula he gave is true? Is it to determine in which cases the formula is true?

Comment: Can you give me ta page of the Ex ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The exercise does not come from the book, is from an exercise list that is based on the book. If you want I can send the exercise to you, but that's basically what I wrote.

Comment: The formula is not valid, but you consider an interpretation in $\mathbb N$ : $∃x¬ (x > 0) → ∀x (0 \le x)$

Comment: The formula is **not** valid because we may easily find a counterexample, using again $\mathbb N$: $∀x(x < 0) \lor ∀x(0 < x)$